# Two ONMOUSEOVER on one source. Javascript

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

I am trying to write JavaScript that has a banner. When I mouse over the banner it changes into a different banner. Then when I mouse out it should stay the same. Then when I mouse back over it should go back to the original banner. However I can't figure out how to do this. Any advice?;

Comment: Can you share the problem code?

Comment: You should have an array and loop through the banners id's on mouseover.

Answer (score 2):

use Javascript

```
<img onmouseover="changeImage()" id="myBanner" src="Images\image1.jpg"/>
<script>
 function changeImage(){
  if(document.getElementById("myBanner").src=="Images\image1.jpg"){
   document.getElementById("myBanner").src="Images\image2.jpg"
  }else{
   document.getElementById("myBanner").src="Images\image1.jpg"
  }
 }
</script>
```

This works for 2 images toggling between each other.  If you want to use more, I suggest using a variable that you pass to the function and a `switch` that goes through all your options.

Comment: Thank you David worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You only need a single mouseover to handle the toggle:

```
(function() {
    var imgTag = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    imgTag.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
        var currentImage = imgTag.getAttribute('src');

        imgTag.setAttribute('src', imgTag.getAttribute('data-other-image'));
        imgTag.setAttribute('data-other-image', currentImage);
    });
}());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EsNEC/

This way you don't have inline javascript in your HTML.